# How to get columns of two dimesional array using functional style in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

For example I have such a simple task: count all raws and columns which have all zeros in 2D array.
So for

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 1
```

answer is 2 raws and 1 column. 
I can make it just like that for raws: `var cntRaws = a.count { it.all { el -> el == 0 } }`, but how to solve it for columns in same way?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid using getters for this. Assuming all rows have equal length, you could do `a.first().indices.count { col -> a.indices.all { a[it][col] == 0 } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val x = Array<IntArray>(3) { IntArray(3) { 0 } }

x[2][0] = 1
x[2][2] = 1
val raws = x.count { it.sum() == 0 }
val columns = (x.indices)
    .map { columnIndex -> x.map { it[columnIndex] } }
    .count { it.sum() == 0 }

println("total raws:$raws")
println("total col:$columns")
```

Comment: `count { it.sum() == 0 }` will be more efficient removing one O(n) steps (since it is not sequence).

Comment: it can work if change x.indices to your one: x.first().indices

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't think of any idomatic / functional style to do this, but I came up with an idea just create a lazily evaluated swapping function that swaps the columns with rows when it wants to pull without creating a new list.

```kotlin
fun <T> List<List<T>>.swapped() = sequence {
    var index = 0
    while (index < size) {
        yield(map { it[index] })
        index++
    }
}

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(
        listOf(0, 0, 0),
        listOf(0, 0, 0),
        listOf(1, 0, 1)
    )

    val cntRows = list.count { it.all { el -> el == 0 } }
    val cntCols = list.swapped().count { it.all { el -> el == 0 } }

    println("cntRows: $cntRows")
    println("cntCols: $cntCols")
}
```

I tried my best to optimize it and do it in same O(n*m) steps as done with the regular row counting, since Sequences are [lazily evaluated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html#sequence).

Comment: Well, still it takes more place than regular 2 fors, but swapped function can be useful in other tasks I think. Anyway thank you

Comment: @IlyaMaximencko it exactly takes O(n*m) steps, the swapped function does not do any operation unless somebody collects the sequence (it is intermediate and stateless). For example count pulls first object then the sequence suspends until `it.all()` has completed and then it pulls second by resuming the suspension. There is no extra stateful list formed in between and the items collected into it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional way of doing it that works if all rows are the same size:

```
fun <T>List<List<T>>.rowToColumn() = (0 until first().size).map{row -> (0 until size).map {col-> this[col][row]  }}
```